# Duplicate Headers received from server - sanitising filenames

Tags: php, linux, unix, recursion, filenames

I am allowing file uploads within my Web application Application.

I have found out how to sanitize the filenames upon upload moving forward. In case anybody is interested -

```
$filename = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\]]|[\.]{2,})", '', $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

What I am looking to do, is recursively look through subfolders of a root folder, and rename all files to remove any `,` or `'` characters in the filename.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! you should post in a question/answer format